# Is there a way to add a menu in putty?

Tags: putty

I was wondering if there is a way, that when I start a session in Putty. That I can run a script that shows a menu in the window. and If I type a number or something, let's say number 1 and hit enter it will run a preprogrammed command?
That way I have a several commands at the ready. But only ran when I select a menu item.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly ask about. Should the menu be displayed and the scripts run on client (local) side or on the remote (server) side? If the latter, the question entirely refers to the server OS, and has nothing to do with PuTTY itself.

Comment: There isn't a remote server we use putty to send serial commands, by typing, for equipment when we need to calibrate them. I made a word document so I could just copy and paste them in. I was thinking if I could load a script into putty when a session is started, or when we connect to equipment, through a com port, and have this script give us options, with those serial commands coded into the script, then being sent to the equipment. Example let say the first menu is    1. Get ID    when I type 1 in a input area, the script would then send *IDN? or what ever it is to the unit

Comment: From my point of view, the script must be executed on client side. I can imagine something like a batch script showing a menu with different option, then sending the appropriate command in background using plink (putty command line tool).

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY can't - to my knowledge - do what you request, but there is a fork of PuTTY called [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) that can probably do what you want. However, it is not in the way you suggest - as a menu with numbered choices - but you can define "command shortcuts" that are integrated into KiTTY menu itself. You can select them from menu in usual way via mouse or via keyboard shortcuts. See [this description](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/Shortcuts.md) of the feature.